# For-loop Hashmap Java

Tags: java, hashmap

Im trying to loop a Hashmap from a certain starting point. My code for now is:

```
for (object o : objects.values()) {
   code in here 
}
```

But now im wondering how i can start the loop at a certain key or value?

Comment: A `HashMap` has no order. Where would you start from?

Comment: Perhaps you should be using `LinkedHashMap` if you are concerned with retreival order.

Comment: You will have to start from the begining of the map and iterate till the end but what is your goal? We could possibly find a better/simpler or more efficient way if we know what the goal is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a "view" that [starts and ends with certain keys](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#subMap-K-K-) by using a `SortedMap` implementation like [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead of a `HashMap`. (You can also simply start at a certain key and process the remainder, without specifying an ending key, by using `tailMap()`.)

```
SortedMap<String, Article> encyclopaedia = new TreeMap<>();
/* Populate the map. */
...
for (Article val : cyc.subMap("Sonar", "Tax Law").values()) {
  /* Process only Volume 17. */
}
```

Note that this will actually exclude "Tax Law" from processing, as the bounds of the sub-map are a half-open interval. If you need to handle cases like that, you can use the further specialization, [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) (which is also implemented by `TreeMap`).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **entrySet** of the Collections and iterate over it...

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {

    System.out.println("The key is:" + entry.getKey());
    System.out.println("The value is:" + entry.getValue());
}
}
```